# How to disable animations for the applications menu?

Tags: menu

I installed elementary tweaks and disabled animations...ordinary windows' animation is gone, however the application menu's animation is still there....

Any way to disable application menu's animation ?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am referring to the animation that happens after closing a window or applications' menu...

Answer (score 1):

Entering this into the terminal should disable those animations completely.

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.animations enable-animations false && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false`

If you'd like to do this in a GUI, search for dconf Editor in AppCenter (or install with `sudo apt install dconf-editor` in the terminal) and install that. Once it's installed, open it up and search for "animation". The results should show two possible toggles, both of which need to be disabled from what I've tested just now.